# Custom Exception class

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have an abstract class Camera. There are some derived classes that will handle specific types of cameras. Every type of camera does has its own exceptions, while some of them do not have exceptions at all, they return an enum with error type.

I want to know if you people agree with this implementation:

All specific classes will handle their exceptions (or enum error type) and will convert it to a generic exception (ex: CameraException : Exception) and throw it.

Is it a good/recommended implementation?

Comment: What are these exceptions? What kinds of things can go wrong, and what do you expect a caller to do about the exceptions?

Comment: ex: Try to start a disconnected camera. Is this case the caller can show in the ui that the camera is not available

Comment: You can do that by providing a `Message` that says "you tried to start a disconnected camera". Also, exceptions are not a good way to update a UI.

Comment: What I mean is something like: try stuff, catch MessageBox.Show(e.Message)

Comment: Exactly. Displaying `ex.Message` works just as well for `InvalidOperationException` as it does for some custom exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application layers should define custom exception types, regardless of what Microsoft says.  Suppose one has an abstract WrappedCamera class, derivatives of which which serve as wrappers around classes like CanonCamera, NikonCamera, KodakCamera, and future derivatives of which will serve as wrappers around classes for cameras designed in future.  Suppose that a class WrappedWaldorfCamera wraps WaldorfCamera, and when it calls WaldorfCamera.GetPictureCount() that method throws exception WaldorfCamera.WrongCameraModeException.  If WrappedWaldorfCamera lets the exception percolate up, what is an application going to do with it?  Unless the application assumes that all unknown exception types should display a message but allow the program to continue, there's no way the application could know that a WaldorfCamera.WrongCameraModeException was safe to catch.  By contrast, if WrappedWaldorfCamera were to throw a WrappedCamera.CameraModeException which derived from WrappedCamera.CleanNonConnectStateException, an application would know that it should catch the exception and handle it.

BTW, lest anyone complain that the whole "problem" was created by WaldorfCamera defining its own exception, consider the situation if instead WrappedWaldorfCamera let percolate an InvalidOperationException.  What should an application do with one of those?

The proper thing to do is for each application layer to define at, at minimum, fatal and non-fatal exception types--typically with a few flavors of each depending upon application state (e.g. CleanNonConnectStateException would imply that a particular camera-connection object doesn't have a valid connection; application code which is prepared to deal with that should catch the exception, while code which isn't prepared to deal with that should let the exception bubble up to code that can handle the situation, rewrapping the exception if it crosses another layer boundary.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to unify the error concepts into a common `CameraException` class hierarchy.  If the goal is to abstract the camera implementaiton, you should abstract the errors as well into this common exception framework.

If you have only implementation-specific exceptions, then it will be very hard for a user of your class to understand exactly what the `CameraException` is trying to say without analyzing the details.

I'd recommend providing a framework of logical exceptions, then your implementation-dependent camera logic will interpret the codes and then create the correct corresponding logical camera exception.

For instance, if you try and perform an operation on the camera's memory, card, and none is inserted, throw a `NoMemoryCardInCameraException` which can inherit from `CameraException`.

If you *really* want those provider details to be available, you could have a property in `CameraException` called `Detail` or something that would be an abstract class or a `Dictionary` of key value pairs with implementation specific details.  That way if someone really wants to dig into the actual error codes, enums, etc from the provider they can.

Your goal should be for the average user to be able to catch logical exceptions and handle them appropriately w/o *needing* to know the specifics.

Hope that clarifies it a bit...

Comment: That is what I was thinking. But people are saying "Converting to generic exceptions usually just hides important information.". I think Ill just throw excpetions in the class that the API does not have its owns excetions (the API only returns enum with the error type).

Comment: @Pedro77: It really, truly depends on what information you have and how important it will be to a user of this generic class. If it is meaningful information that they can act upon, then by all means create a hierarchy with a common base exception type (CameraException), but if it's exceptions due to logical errors (i.e. NotConnectedCameraException, NoMemoryCardCameraException, etc) then you should just have a hierarchy that supports the logical errors and hide the error codes.

Answer (score 2):

You should only create a new Exception type if a caller is going to catch that specific type, or if some caller is going to know about the specific type and look at it's properties.

If callers of the different camera types will do nothing more than this:

```
try
{
    // Do something with some kind of camera
}
catch (CameraException ex)
{
    // Handle the fact that there was a camera problem
}
```

Then there is no need for custom derived types of `CameraException`. Nobody cares what particular derived type was thrown.

In fact, if your callers will do nothing different when `CameraException` is thrown vs. any other kind of exception, then there is no need for a `CameraException`. Simply use something like `InvalidOperationException` and throw it with an informative `Message` property:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException(
    String.Format("Invalid attempt to set the f-stop to {0} while in video mode",
                  this.FStop));
```

Comment: Well, no, in the case where you currently return an enum, you presumably have callers who are looking at the return value. In that case, you should probably continue returning error codes, unless you're prepared to change all the callers to use exception handling. If so, then it makes sense to have a custom exception type which can contain the `enum`. The callers could then still use the code that depended on the `enum`.

Comment: the caller will know only the abstract camera, they dont care what is the especific type! So every derived camera class must behavior the same. If the API does not have exeptions, I will thrown one with the error returned by the called method.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to generic exceptions usually just hides important information.
Having all exceptions inherit `CameraException` can be a good thing, but let the different implementations subclass `CameraException` if they find it useful.

Comment: I think the issue is that exceptions may be thrown by portions of the implementations which were written by people who know nothing about the Camera class, and such exceptions will thus almost certainly not derive from CameraException.  Letting such an exception bubble up through an entire application layer without being wrapped is a bad idea, since code at a higher level won't have any way to determine what layer the exception came from--much less what should be done with it.